# Creating a vector dynamically

Tags: r

I have a comma-separated config file with 2 elements:

```
Attribute,  Method
------------------
   Design,    Text
Objective,    Text
 Adaptive, Boolean
```

I am reading the config file as below:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(Attributes)) {
    if (Attributes$Method[i]=='Text') {
        output<- doc[i:End_Line];
    }
}
```

The problem is: For each attribute in the config file, I'd like to write to a separate   vector with the name created dynamically using the Attribute name from Config file.

So at the end of the run, I am hoping to have 3 different vectors.

I tried using: `output$Attributes$Attribute <- doc[i:End_Line]`
but no luck. Wondering if anyone has done this before?

Thanks a lot in advance,
Simak

Comment: 2 elements followed by 4 objects, this is confusing. Perhaps show the contents of  the config file, and what you would like the result to be.

Comment: sorry - reformatted. hope its clear now?

Comment: Would the first be like: `c("design", "text")` with the name "design" or would it have the name "design", containing only "text"?

Comment: It's too unclear, please provide a short sample file and the expected R output.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear and wasting your time...I guess, I figured it out. I was trying to generate a "vector" for each attribute I read from the file. Instead, I am working with lists and it is working fine. Thanks again for answering the post and my apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might start with this, since I am still not really sure what it is you are after:

```
data <- read.csv("file.csv")
rownames(data) <- data[,1]
data
```

You can then easily access them separately like this:

```
data[1,]
data[2,]
```

But also like this: `data["Adaptive", ]`

Let me know, I'll update the answer accordingly.